# Passing Info From form to form Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a very basic form that I want to pass data from another form on it without using php at all. Both forms appear properly but I cannot figure out how to transfer data from the first form to the second one with javascript code.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action"" method="get" onsubmit="submitForm();" name="submitForm">

            Company Name:<input type="text"name="companyName"><br><br>
            Owner: <input type="text" name="compOwner"><br><br>
            Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br><br>
            Phone Number:<input type="text" name="phoneNum"><br><br>
            Annual Sales($)<input type="text" name="annualSales"><br><br>
            Borrow Amount($)<input type="text" name="borrowAmount"><br><br>
            Payment Terms(Months)<input type="text" name="paymentTerms"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();">
        </form>

        <form action"" method="get" name="secondForm">
            Name of Borrowing Company<input type="text"id="compName"><br><br>
            Annual Sales<input type="text"id="annSales"><br><br>
            Borrow Amount<input type="text"id="amountBorrowed"><br><br>
            Payment Terms<input type="text"id="payTerms"><br><br>

            Total Interest On Loan<input type="text"id="totalInterest"><br><br>
            Total Payment<input type="text"id="totalPay"><br><br>
            Total Profit <input type="text"enabled="false" id="totalProfit"><br><br>




        </form>
            <script>
            function submitForm()
            {
                compName = document.forms["submitForm"]["companyName"].value;
                annualSales = document.forms["submitForm"]["annualSales"].value;
                borrowAmount = document.forms["submitForm"]["borrowAmount"].value;
                months = document.forms["submitForm"]["paymentTerms"].value;
                totalInterest = borrowAmount * (months/12) * 0.03;
                totalPayment = borrowAmount + totalInterest;
                profit = totalPayment - borrowAmount;


                document.getElementById('compName').setAttribute(value, compName);
                document.getElementById('annSales').value = annualSales;
                document.getElementById('amountBorrowed').value = borrowAmount;
                document.getElementById('payTerms').value = months;
                document.getElementById('totalInterest').value = totalInterest;
                document.getElementById('totalPay').value = totalPayment;
                document.getElementById('totalProfit').value = profit;

            }
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There are several problems with this code actually.

First, name of the first form element clashes with name of your function. That is because when an element has a `name` attribute, it creates a new variable in JS global scope and rewrites your function, because it has the same name. Your form name attribute must be something else that your function name.

```
<form action"" method="get" onsubmit="submitForm();" name="submitF">
```

Next, `input type="submit"` refreshes the page, which you probably don't want. You could add a button element after the form.

```
</form>
<button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

In JS, submitF is a variable with your form element (thanks to the `name` attribute), so you can write it simpler without use of `document.forms`.

```
function submitForm() {
    compName = submitF["companyName"].value;
    annualSales = submitF["annualSales"].value;
    borrowAmount = submitF["borrowAmount"].value;
    months = submitF["paymentTerms"].value;
    (...)
}
```

Also, `setAttribute(value, compName)` doesn't work. It just doesn't. Assign to `value` instead like in the rest of the code.

My whole working code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitForm() {
                compName = submitF["companyName"].value;
                annualSales = submitF["annualSales"].value;
                borrowAmount = submitF["borrowAmount"].value;
                months = submitF["paymentTerms"].value;
                totalInterest = borrowAmount * (months/12) * 0.03;
                totalPayment = borrowAmount + totalInterest;
                profit = totalPayment - borrowAmount;


                document.getElementById('compName').value = compName;
                document.getElementById('annSales').value = annualSales;
                document.getElementById('amountBorrowed').value = borrowAmount;
                document.getElementById('payTerms').value = months;
                document.getElementById('totalInterest').value = totalInterest;
                document.getElementById('totalPay').value = totalPayment;
                document.getElementById('totalProfit').value = profit;
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action"" method="get" onsubmit="submitForm();" name="submitF">

            Company Name:<input type="text"name="companyName"><br><br>
            Owner: <input type="text" name="compOwner"><br><br>
            Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br><br>
            Phone Number:<input type="text" name="phoneNum"><br><br>
            Annual Sales($)<input type="text" name="annualSales"><br><br>
            Borrow Amount($)<input type="text" name="borrowAmount"><br><br>
            Payment Terms(Months)<input type="text" name="paymentTerms"><br><br>


        </form>
        <button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
        <form action"" method="get" name="secondForm">
            Name of Borrowing Company<input type="text"id="compName"><br><br>
            Annual Sales<input type="text"id="annSales"><br><br>
            Borrow Amount<input type="text"id="amountBorrowed"><br><br>
            Payment Terms<input type="text"id="payTerms"><br><br>

            Total Interest On Loan<input type="text"id="totalInterest"><br><br>
            Total Payment<input type="text"id="totalPay"><br><br>
            Total Profit <input type="text"enabled="false" id="totalProfit"><br><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's it. Hope I helped.

EDIT: Also, you should always put your JS code in your `<head>`, unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: This helped a ton. Im a first year IT student so I was actually unaware that it would rewrite the JS function. Thanks so much for the advice really helped a bunch! :)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to change     `document.getElementById('compName').setAttribute(value, compName);`
to 
`document.getElementById('compName').value = compName;`

Also, you should convert your number values from String to an Integer
ex. 
`annualSales = parseInt(document.forms["submitForm"]["annualSales"].value)`

Other than that, the javascript seems fine.

UPDATE:

Upon investigating further. Your submit is occurring before the javascript is run, that is why the fields are not getting populated. I would suggest you put your javascript in an event listener for submit.

```
document.forms['submitForm'].submit(function() {
    compName = document.forms["submitForm"]["companyName"].value;
    annualSales = document.forms["submitForm"]["annualSales"].value;
    borrowAmount = document.forms["submitForm"]["borrowAmount"].value;
    months = document.forms["submitForm"]["paymentTerms"].value;
    totalInterest = borrowAmount * (months/12) * 0.03;
    totalPayment = borrowAmount + totalInterest;
    profit = totalPayment - borrowAmount;

    document.getElementById('compName').setAttribute(value, compName);
    document.getElementById('annSales').value = annualSales;
    document.getElementById('amountBorrowed').value = borrowAmount;
    document.getElementById('payTerms').value = months;
    document.getElementById('totalInterest').value = totalInterest;
    document.getElementById('totalPay').value = totalPayment;
    document.getElementById('totalProfit').value = profit;
});
```

NOTE: Your page will refresh when you do a submit, and you won't see the values be populated.

Comment: I think he has the click function in the button AND the form submit, maybe that's why it fires off too soon like that. Either don't make the button be a submit, but have the onclick, or don't have onclick and use onsubmit...?